# What is the best way to learn jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I am new to [ASP.NET MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET_MVC_Framework) and [jQuery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery). What is the best way to learn jQuery? Are there any good links, blogs, and screencasts?

Comment: Please post research you've done so that people can make more-specific recommendations. Thank you. I fear this question will get closed as "not constructive" for being too broad...

Comment: http://robinz.in/begin-with-jquery/

Comment: For beginners here is  great resource to learn basics of jquery in 15 minutes. Link: https://haroonejaz.net/learn-jquery-in-15-minutes-on-youtube/

Answer (score 48, accepted):

I struggled with [jQuery in Action](http://www.manning.com/bibeault/) because I felt it was more of a reference manual as opposed to a tutorial.  Maybe a year ago it was the best reference/tutorial, but now there are a bunch of other alternatives.

On the other hand, I really enjoyed the book [Javascript: The Missing Manual](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596515898) because I felt it had better examples.  Don't let the title of the book fool you, after a quick introduction to JavaScript the author introduces you to jQuery and uses jQuery for the rest of the book.

I also purchased two PDF Books from [Packt Publishing](http://www.packtpub.com/) :

1) [Learning jQuery 1.3](http://www.packtpub.com/learning-jquery-1.3/book)

2) [jQuery UI 1.6: The User Interface Library for jQuery](http://www.packtpub.com/user-interface-library-for-jquery/book)

Both are recent publications and well written.  You can often find "percentage off" discounts from your local user group or on the internet to apply to the purchase price of the downloadable PDF books.

If you're looking for a single book that covers both jQuery and the jQuery UI project, then this Wrox book might be useful: [Beginning JavaScript and CSS Development with jQuery](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470227796).   A quick google search revealed that you can browse *some* of the contents of the book online at: [Google Book Search - Beginning JavaScript Development With jQuery
 By Richard York](http://books.google.com/books?id=AHBPmBruZo8C)

I would actually recommend learning from samples posted on the web.   There are a bunch over at:

[Learning jQuery - a site related to the Packt book listed above](http://www.learningjquery.com/)

[Encosia - ASP.NET, AJAX and more](http://encosia.com/)

[ASP.NET and MVC jQuery related posts at Haacked](http://haacked.com/tags/jquery/default.aspx)

[Rick Strahl's Web Log](http://www.west-wind.com/Weblog/ShowPosts.aspx?Category=jQuery)

Comment: I think "JavaScript: The Missing Manual" is one of the best JS books out there.

Comment: I learnt most of the power by watching these videos on nettuts http://net.tutsplus.com/articles/news/learn-jquery-in-30-days/ .You code along and learn about sliding effects all things beutiful by coding along. Really good.

Comment: For anyone wanting to learn jQuery quickly while producing useful code I would recommended a cookbook such as these: http://www.revillweb.com/jquery-book-jquery-2-0-development-cookbook/ & http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596159788.do. I'm pretty biased with the first one :)

Answer (score 6):

I always learn best with a project,  a deadline and an unforgiving client.

Also "JQuery in Action" is a decent book.

Answer (score 4):

Build something.  Try to build, say, a calculator application using clickable divs instead of buttons and storing data in the html content instead of in javascript variables.  This kind of exercise will give you a crappy calculator but good experience in manipulating things.

Comment: cannot build a chair without knowing how to cut wood

Answer (score 4):

The best way to learn is to start building something. You can take any personal project of yours and try to implement jQuery on it. Another good way to learn any technology is to take part in forums. You are at the right place (StackOverFlow)! There is a tag for JQuery which you can use to see all the JQuery questions. Try to find solution to the problems. This will help you and also the other person who is trying to look for the answer!

There is also a 38 Minute FREE JQuery Video that you might want to see to get started.

http://highoncoding.com/Videos/537_Extended_Screencast_on_JQuery_Whole_38_Minutes_.aspx

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest familiarizing yourself with JavaScript first. Books from the likes of o'reilly are always a good resource.

As for jQuery, their documentation site is fantastic. http://docs.jquery.com

Good luck!

Comment: I actually find their docs really terse and hard to browse :/

Comment: Script.aculo.us and Prototype docs are much, much worse.

Answer (score 3):

The jQuery docs are very good.  They also have a really cool api that you can use to easily navigate the docs, http://api.jquery.com.

I'm an ASP.NET developer and I found Rich Strahl's blog has a really good intro. [An introduction to jQuery (2 Parts)](http://www.west-wind.com/Weblog/posts/558952.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

I'm learning it while trying to answer questions on JQuery here in Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 2):

Some ways that I learnt

- Get JQuery in ACtion book.
- tutorials on [docs.jquery.com](http://docs.jquery.com) are
  pretty good as well
- [nettuts](http://www.nettuts.com) and [smashing magazine](http://www.smashingmagazine.com)

Answer (score 1):

[JQuery in action](http://www.manning.com/bibeault/) is the best book on this topic.

Comment: I agree. I also learned from that book a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Nettuts has some very nice video tutorials, a great place to start at.
[jquery for absolute beginners](http://nettuts.com/articles/web-roundups/jquery-for-absolute-beginners-video-series/)

Answer (score 1):

I learned jQuery through reading a book called [jQuery: Novice to Ninja](http://www.sitepoint.com/books/jquery1/).  For a time, the PDF was freely downloadable, so I figured 'what the heck', but it was actually a really good book and was a very easy-to-read and pretty thorough examination of what jQuery can do for you.  I recommend it!

Kyle

Answer (score 1):

Personally I think that it's better to start off by understanding JavaScript. I recommend JavaScript: The Good Parts by Douglas Crockford to anyone who is starting out, particularly those who are experienced with other languages. The syntax of JS makes the language seem deceptively familiar. Once you are comfortable with JS then you will probably know how to best approach learning jQuery (if you can just read docs/examples or if you need to read a more instructional book like those which have been suggested). I never "learnt" jQuery. To me it's just like any other library and I read the docs for usage, but I actually prefer not to use it when I don't need it.

Answer (score 0):

I've found that the best way to learn programming languages/frameworks is to go through the docs and play with them.

Answer (score 0):

I learned jQuery by reading 4pages article from php magazine. After short introduction just try demos form jQuery docs - that really is the best way. Don't waste time for reading books, it consumes a lot of time, and after that you will still have to test it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Read through every single section of this: http://api.jquery.com and you will know just about everything about it--not all the best practices, though... those come with time and experience. Your best bet is to think about something you want to do and then just do it while utilizing different pertinent parts of jQuery.

I originally learned using http://visualjquery.com/ but that hasn't been updated since 1.2.6 (because it is now the aforementioned api.jquery.com). I wouldn't be where I am with the library today if it weren't for those two websites (thank you Remy Sharp!).

Answer (score 0):

The best way to learn jQuery is to code while you're at it. Now, I consider myself as a newbie in both Javascript and jQuery but I'm doing some personal projects that I'm going to release soon when I received my own server. The projects are small and jQuery related.

I develop plugins, animation plugins that animate the body of the page. I develop a slideshow for images. But you know what, I think jQuery really makes thing damn simple. Especially for animation.

I'm afraid that I'm gonna lose my knowledge in Javascript once I program in jQuery for too long.

I also recommend you to emulate the flash designs in Javascript. If you go to Gamespot.com, you'll see that their designs are flash. Try to do something similar using jQuery/Javascript.

Hey, and you got your own style of learning. I learn by reading the book. Once I finished reading the book I'll go sit down on my computer and program everything I learned. If I forgot something, I'll just open the book and find the reference. I found it the best way to learn programming. But you might have different style of learning. Maybe you prefer reading and programming at the same time. Or checking out the source code and learning from there.

Do some blogging in your portfolio. Detail how you created the jQuery plugins. Contribute to jQuery. Make people use your plugin. Share some love.