# how to shift from JavaScript to jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, cross-browser

jQuery is a framework of javaScript. But, I very well able to code in javaScript. I am not getting how do I (re)code it in jQuery !

Is learning jQuery from beginning is only way or should I follow any other way ?

EDIT : is jQuery used only for AJAX ? or where can I find proper to use jQuery ?

Comment: you might find this useful:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/836725/what-is-the-best-way-to-learn-jquery

Comment: You can you use something without learning it?

Comment: someone gone crazy giving negative flags :-)

Comment: however, doesn't matter ! I found my answer & thanks for all your warm helps !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to learn jQuery in order to use it, yes.

(You don't, however, use jQuery instead of JavaScript. You might use it instead of directly using DOM, XHR and so on, but it *is* JavaScript)

Comment: Thanks David. Can I have proper online documentation of where to use jQuery (if any) ?

Comment: Well, strictly speaking, yes, jQuery is JavaScript. But jQuery doesn't look like javaScript, doesn't feel like JavaScript and doesn't smell JavaScript. So I'm not considering it's really JavaScript... There is very few knowledge you have from JavaScript that will help you at using jQuery.

Comment: I am not a jQuery expert, but I do everything in jQuery and I have never read a proper book on the subject. The documentation at jquery.com is easy to find, navigate and follow. I would just forget js and do everything in jQuery from this very moment, you will have no problem.

Comment: It looks, smells and feels like JavaScript to me.

Comment: Thanks a lot to all ! Let me start Quering the "j" !

Comment: +1 to the original answer and to David's latest comment. The more you understand jQuery, the more javascripty it feels.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery is JavaScript. It's just another tool. Its big benefit is that you can manipulate the DOM and perform AJAX requests much easier.

For example, to get all links by class name in JavaScript (using [this function](http://robertnyman.com/2005/11/07/the-ultimate-getelementsbyclassname/)) is:

```
function getElementsByClassName(className, tag, elm){
    var testClass = new RegExp("(^|\\s)" + className + "(\\s|$)");
    var tag = tag || "*";
    var elm = elm || document;
    var elements = (tag == "*" && elm.all)? elm.all : elm.getElementsByTagName(tag);
    var returnElements = [];
    var current;
    var length = elements.length;
    for(var i=0; i<length; i++){
        current = elements[i];
        if(testClass.test(current.className)){
            returnElements.push(current);
        }
    }
    return returnElements;
}

var elements = getElementsByClassName(document,'a','myclass');
```

The same using jQuery*:

```
var elements = $("a.myclass");
```

Of course, jQuery would do similar things behind the scenes but the point is that you don't need to know about it (and more importantly, don't need to rewrite it all). There are lots of people coming up with clever things for jQuery (and tests, so you know it works cross browser).

Use [jsFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net) to quickly play with some examples in jQuery (look at the [jQuery docs](http://docs.jquery.com)). Don't necessarily set out to rewrite your entire JavaScript using jQuery. Just start using it for DOM operations/AJAX requests (even something as simple as using the [show](http://api.jquery.com/show/) or [hide](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) methods). Eventually you'll get used to using jQuery and eye up your older code to rewrite. Just to give you an example, I once rewrote a 200-300 line piece of JavaScript into about 20 lines with jQuery. The reason for the massive difference is because I was able to remove all the 'helper' functions (like getElementsByClassName one above) since jQuery handles that for me.

Good luck :)

---

* The pedantic among you will know it's not *entirely* the same, since it returns the jQuery object - but this can really be ignored because it'll do the same result.

Comment: If we ignore the fact that most browsers have an implementation of getElementsByClassName these days; the key difference between "using jQuery" and "writing all that" is just that "jQuery includes a version of that written by someone else".

Comment: Yeah - that's what I was getting at (and, importantly, they've got unit tests). Probably should have picked a better example than getElementsByClassName - although to limit elements by tag name and class name still requires a bit of coding in pure JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Rewriting existing javascript code to take advantage of the jQuery framework will require you knowledge of jQuery. There's no other way. In fact there is: you could hire someone doing the job for you but I don't think this was your original question.

Answer (score 0):

There's no easy answer on that question. Learn the fundamentals of jQuery then rewrite your code from scratch. 
As with all new languages/concepts start small and then get bolder..

But from someone who did the transition, I can say that the effort was worth it!

Enjoy learning jQuery!

Comment: Definitely ! I need to start from the root !

Answer (score 0):

My advice is don't go for recoding the entire javascript at first time.

First take a small parts in a javascript for show and hide the div or table or any other elements.Then you will do it by using Jquery.After getting success on this you will get some confidence.

Then go for ajax using Jquery.

By this way you can learning the Jquery and step by step you changed your javascript to jquery.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Ok ! So, I think I should start with accessing basic CSS properties of HTML elements & then gradually towards modify it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm quite surprised this hasn't been mentioned before now. But one of the absolutely best sources for beginners is the well written and open sourced *book* [jQuery Fundamentals](http://jqfundamentals.com/book/book.html) by Rebecca Murphey.

It will walk you through the basics of both JavaScript and jQuery, and will hopefully be the only thing (together with the docs) you'll need to get you going with jQuery!

I also recommend this for more advanced users because it will help you break free of bad practices that you might have picked up from, I'm sad to say it, badly written tutorials or books.

Happy reading!

Answer (score -2):

jQuery isnt very different. It just combines some of the best features of javascript and uses CSS selectors to give you a easy to use language. Where most of the typical lines of code can be converted into smaller jQuery statements just start following a few examples and u will by default start moving to learning jQuery more.

Comment: Thanks Shushil ! I think CSS support is most appropriate option where you prefer to use jQuery. Is it ?

Comment: jQuery isnt different from javascript. You can call it javascript extended so if u love javascript you will have to learn jQuery to write your javascript fast and clean. Moreover jQuery is not just about selectors its about its utitlity functions, its cross-browser compatible solutions and about its numerous plugins. Learn jQuery for the love of javascript. As i feel i haved started knowing javascript more only after learning jQuery.